# Trying to use a QGIS plugin - getting classFactory error

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I've had to create a GIS for the company I work for, choosing QGIS over ArcGIS due to price (company doesn't want to buy another copy of ArcMap). In any case, it's not a HUGE GIS but it would be good to be able to search for features quickly and easily - just by typing in. It seems QGIS doesn't support this as easily as the users want to use it, so I've tried downloading the Quickfinder plugin.

In any case, after eventually finding out how to install it (as it will be offline when in use, so had to download the zip and extract to the correct place), QGIS has found it but can't install it, saying it's broken and can't call it's classFactory() method. The full code (with my project name removed due to confidentiality issues) is below:

```
Couldn't load plugin quickfinder due an error when calling its classFactory() method

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISDU~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 204, in startPlugin
plugins[packageName] = package.classFactory(iface)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'classFactory'

Python version:
2.7.4 (default, Apr  6 2013, 19:54:46) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]


QGIS version:
2.0.1-Dufour Dufour, ebebdf3

Python path: ['C:/PROGRA~1/QGISDU~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\\processing',
'C:/PROGRA~1/QGISDU~1/apps/qgis/./python',
'C:\\Documents and Settings\\my.name/.qgis2/python',
'C:\\Documents and Settings\\my.name/.qgis2/python/plugins',
'C:/PROGRA~1/QGISDU~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins',
'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISDU~1\\bin\\python27.zip',
'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISDU~1\\apps\\Python27\\DLLs',
'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISDU~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib',
'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISDU~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win',
'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISDU~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk',
'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISDU~1\\bin',
'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISDU~1\\apps\\Python27',
'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISDU~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages',
'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISDU~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\PIL',
'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISDU~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\win32',
'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISDU~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',
'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISDU~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin',
'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISDU~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\wx-2.8-msw-unicode',
'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISDU~1\\apps\\qgis\\python\\plugins\\fTools\\tools',
'C:/map stuff/MyProject']
```

Does anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Where did you get the plugin from? If it is designed for QGIS 1.8.0, it will not work in QGIS 2.0.1 due to large API changes.

Current version of the Quick Finder Plugin is 2.6.2, and it works with QGIS 2.0.1

If the computer is offline, try to download the plugin on another computer with internet access, and copy the folder from user/.qgis2/python/plugins from one PC to the other.

Comment: Got it from http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/quickfinder/ and it should work with 2.0.0 (according to it). The computer I'm building it on isn't offline, but may as well be as the IT dept stop me from using any repositories (it won't connect). Downloaded it to the location you said and will be transferring it over to the PC it is to be used on as you say (as that one will have the same restrictions).

Comment: I just downloaded and expanded the zip from the site you mentioned, and it works for me the same way as the plugin loaded the normal way.

Comment: Sorted it, I think. I hadn't actually installed it correctly. I'd extracted the zip to the correct place, but not extracted the zip correctly (just extracted the files, not the subfolders). Nevertheless, Andre's done the most research so I'll mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you use **QGIS 2.0.1 Dufour** just go to `Plugins > Manage and Install Plugins`:

[image]

Then go to `Get more`, choose **QuickFinder** and press `Install Plugin`.
You'll obtain this:

[image]

Comment: I'm afraid you are wrong: apps/qgis/./python/plugins is the default path for core plugins, while username/.qgis2/python plugins is the path for all other plugins. So everything should be ok with the settings.

Comment: @Andre: you are right. Thank you for your pertinent observation!

Answer (score 0):

I could solve this problem by setting the text editor: If you are using Notepad++, makes sure to check Replace by space at Settings ‣ Preferences ‣ Tab Settings. Python is very sensitive about whitespace and this setting will ensure tabs and spaces are treated properly.

Comment: I think this answer is not pertinent to the question.